# How to share memory between http requests in g-wan?

Tags: persistence, g-wan

Lets say I have a g-wan server with c script, if a http request comes in and then another http request, I would like for both of these running scripts to be able to read and write from the same section of ram.

In other words, I wish to just have a simple RAM database, an array of data and any http request can read from this RAM database.

I mean for any HTTP request to this server, it could be from any client. I just want to be able to read or write from the same data in RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `US_SERVER_DATA`:

```
US_SERVER_DATA,      // global pointer (for maintenance script)
```

Comment: What does for maintenance script mean?

Comment: Maintenance script = async script that do background works, named main.c in g-wan main directory.

Comment: Also check out this link for persistence pointer of your need: http://gwan.com/source/persistence.c

Comment: Unix also supports shared memory that you can use (that's a system feature) to survive a ./gwan process stop/restrat. Of course, you can also use SQLite (memory based or disk based), see the G-WAN examples.